# Using stack in windows MASM program

Tags: x86, masm32

I'm writing simple MASM application in WinAsm Studio and I encountered a problem with the stack.
I've been able to recreate it in this very simple program:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
OPTION CASEMAP:NONE 

Include windows.inc
Include kernel32.inc
Include masm32.inc
include user32.inc
IncludeLib kernel32.lib
IncludeLib masm32.lib
IncludeLib user32.lib 

.code
aProc proc near
  push 1
  ret
aProc endp

bProc proc near
  pop edx
  ret
bProc endp

start:
  call aProc
  call bProc
  invoke ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

What I'm trying to do in this example is to put a few values onto the stack in one procedure (`aProc`) and then retrieve them in another procedure (`bProc`).

Can you explain to me why this code causes the program to crash (`Access violation`) and how to use the stack properly?

Comment: push 1 followed by a ret will attempt to return to location 1. Also start will need a ret instruction or some type of OS exit call.

Comment: I skipped ret for start in this example to make it simpler. Already fixed.

Comment: About the first thing: does that means that I can't use stack inside procedure?

Comment: You can, but the return address is also on the stack, so you must take that fact into account. You can first pop it in a register, push you value, then push it back on top of the stack, then you can ret.

Comment: Your problem is: You **do not** comprehend the concept of a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). A _Stack_ is a _LIFO_ datatype.